# How to get monthly counts between two Date IDs in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get monthly counts between the range of two dates. For example lets take the following range:

20181202 - 20190202

This range will give a +1 to the counts of "December" for 2018 and "January", "February" for 2019.

Currently I am aggregating by month and year to get these counts but I forgot about the case for when a there is more than 1 year gap between the dates.

Query right now looks something like this:

```
    CREATE VIEW V_A_A AS
SELECT CASE WHEN 01>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 01<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 'JAN'
WHEN 02>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 02<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'FEB'
WHEN 03>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 03<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'MAR'
WHEN 04>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 04<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'APR'
WHEN 05>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 05<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'MAY'
WHEN 06>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 06<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'JUNE'
WHEN 07>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 07<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'JULY'
WHEN 08>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 08<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'AUG'
WHEN 09>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 09<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'SEPT'
WHEN 10>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 10<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'OCT'
WHEN 11>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 11<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'NOV'
WHEN 12>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 12<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'DEC' ELSE 'N/A' END MONTH
,CASE WHEN 2019>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2019<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2019 
WHEN 2018>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2018<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2018
WHEN 2017>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2017<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2017
WHEN 2016>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2016<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2016
WHEN 2015>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2015<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2015 ELSE 0 END YEAR
,COUNT(*) AS COUNT
from 
(select * from some_db a
INNER JOIN another_db b ON a.field = b.field
WHERE a.name = "Private" JT 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN 2019>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2019<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2019 
WHEN 2018>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2018<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2018
WHEN 2017>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2017<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2017
WHEN 2016>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2016<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2016
WHEN 2015>=JT.SUBSTR(START,1,4) AND 2015<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 2015 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN 01>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 01<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,1,4) THEN 'JAN'
WHEN 02>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 02<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'FEB'
WHEN 03>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 03<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'MAR'
WHEN 04>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 04<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'APR'
WHEN 05>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 05<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'MAY'
WHEN 06>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 06<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'JUNE'
WHEN 07>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 07<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'JULY'
WHEN 08>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 08<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'AUG'
WHEN 09>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 09<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'SEPT'
WHEN 10>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 10<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'OCT'
WHEN 11>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 11<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'NOV'
WHEN 12>=JT.SUBSTR(START,5,2) AND 12<=JT.SUBSTR(ENDID,5,2) THEN 'DEC' ELSE 'N/A' END
```

Comment: Which data type is your `start` and `endid` column? What values are stored inside? Give an example.

Comment: They are number datatypes, examples can be seen above (20181202, 20190202)

Comment: are you trying to get the number of months between two dates(begin and end months are inclusive) ? E.g. do you want to get 3 from the sample input ..? or list all months such as `2018DEC - 2019JAN - 2019FEB` ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I want to the view to produce a result where year would be a column, month would be a column and count would be a column. Beginning and end months are inclusive! So in the row that contains year 2018, month December there should be a count of 1 in this case (there should be counts of one for all other valid months as well).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you need whole years of boundary dates(2018 - 2019 in this case ). So there should be 24 rows. And if those 24 months coincide with months of the interval between the boundary dates, then you need a count of one, else zero. So, consider :

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t1.months,1,4) as "Year", 
       TO_CHAR( TO_DATE(t1.months,'yyyymm'), 'Month' ) as "Month",
       NVL2(t2.months,1,0) as "Count"
  FROM
  (
SELECT y.years||m.months as months
  FROM
  (
   SELECT DISTINCT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('20181202','yyyymmdd') , level - 1 ),'yyyy')
          as years
     FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 
    MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('20190202','yyyymmdd'),TO_DATE('20181202','yyyymmdd')) + 1 ) y
   CROSS JOIN
   (
    SELECT LPAD(LEVEL,2,'0') months
      FROM dual
   CONNECT BY level <= 12
   ) m
  ) t1
 LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('20181202','yyyymmdd') , level - 1 ),'yyyymm')
          as months
     FROM dual
  CONNECT BY level <= 
      MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE('20190202','yyyymmdd'),TO_DATE('20181202','yyyymmdd')) + 1
 ) t2
 ON t1.months = t2.months
 ORDER BY t1.months
```

where `CROSS JOIN` and then `LEFT JOIN` recursively.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4384d1036c0da4126ea0fd2ffb98edc5)</kbd>

Comment: Could you possibly give a brief explanation for what you are doing here? As my username suggests I am pretty new to these concepts :/.

Comment: I firstly need to ask is this the result which you want ? @novice_programmer9623

Comment: I determined all years and all months of those years the boundary dates touch in the first step, and then generated #of years times 12 months by CROSS JOIN( e.g. CARTESIAN PRODUCT ) and used LEFT JOIN to keep all the rows generated rows in the first step. During all this I generated year-month pairs for date range as the rightmost subquery and considered their counts as 1 others as 0 by the nature of LEFT JOIN mechanism through null values coming from this rightmost subquery @novice_programmer9623 .

Comment: Thank you, is there anyway I can use the START and ENDID fields within this query? I am getting an error saying that START could not be found when I replace your FROM clause with the original join I had

Comment: you're welcome @novice_programmer9623 .  `start` is a reserved keyword that cannot be a column name unless quoted ("start" or "START" or "sTaRt" vice versa...), you can replace with `startid` as an example. Btw, `20181202` might be replace with `'&startid'` and `20190202` with `'&endid'` substitution variables within your query.

Comment: hmm when I use the substitution variables the query is still not working...